# Concatenate/Append png images into single Document (any format)

Tags: vb.net, image, pdf, append

I have a routine to generate png images from a form (1 to 35 image).
I need to append a variable number of this images for printing.Maybe appending on a single pdf or any kind of document, the goal is to automate printing. I can figure out how to print one by one, but i need to use a A4 page (4 images per page). Do you know anything about this, i have been trying with PdfSharp but i cant't figure out how to do this.

Any suggestion, link or code is welcome.

Thank you. Best regards
Diego Porras

Comment: `PdfSharp` can do it. You need to use the `AddPage` and `XGraphics.FromPdfPage` to add images to each page.

Comment: Actually i needed multiple images in a single page. As far i know xgraph draws an image per page, doesn't IT? Thanks

Comment: Then draw them to smaller rectangles on one page.

Answer (score 0):

A developer  gave me this code for concatenate images (in my code I use png formatted images but you might change image format)I have made small fixes myself and this is the result):

[See Code for concatenate images](http://pastebin.com/eA1dcTS0)